# Negating closing square bracket in a JS RegExp character class

Tags: javascript, regex

Am trying to negate a closing square brackek in javascript regular expression using the String.prototype.match method, and its returning null.

Code example.

```
// trying to match [value]
// expected regex to match a [ followed by one or more character except ] then a ].

"text[value]".match(/\[[^]]+\]/);

// returns null
```

Comment: Escape the `]` inside the character class. `"text[value]".match(/\[[^\]]+\]/);`

Comment: I tried this before and it worked, except it also negate the \ as well.

Comment: You don't say so. How? Please post the snippet showing what is wrong with the `/\[[^\]]+\]/` regex. It will match [`[str\str]` in `str[str\str]`](https://regex101.com/r/TofVz3/1).

Comment: Testing that regex against a string that has a \ will match to the first \, in my case I want it to match upto the first ]. For example "@text[v\alue]".match(/\[[^\]]+\]/); will return null

Comment: You are wrong. See my answer with `console.log("text1[value2\\value3]".match(/\[[^\]]+]/));` that outputs `[value2\value3]`. Also, see [another fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zvs7k5zg/).

Comment: Ooh right, I fogot you also have to escape the slash \\ on the string thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always ecape the closing `]` inside a JS regular expression character class (note that a `]` outside character class does not have to be escaped to be parsed as a literal `]`):

```js
console.log("text1[value1]".match(/\[[^\]]+\]/));
console.log("text1[value2]".match(/\[[^\]]+]/));
console.log("text1[value2\\value3]".match(/\[[^\]]+]/));
```

Otherwise, it closes the character class prematurely, and may cause issues like the one you have. Your `\[[^]]+\]` pattern matches `[`, then any char (as `[^]` is a valid construct in JS that matches any char including a newline and CR), and then 1 or more literal `]` symbols (as `]` outside a character class does not have to be escaped, and then `]`. See [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CmG9Ch/1) that finds a match in `"str[\n]]]]]]]]]"`.